# A Plus (+) sign appearing on iTextSharp generate pdf form using PdfStamper

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I have used iTextSharp to generate an editable pdf form using PdfStamper class from iTextSharp.

Everything is fine except that when the cell contains too many characters then on focusing out of the editable cell a plus sign will show up against such cells.

**How can I prevent this?** May be there is a setting that I may not be aware of at the field level.

**No plus sign when cell contents are not too long**

[image: No Plus Sign when cell contents are not too large]

**Plus sign when cell contents are long**

[image: Plus Sign Showing when cell contents are large]

The C# code I am using to generate the editable form is as below.

```
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(
                 new RandomAccessFileOrArray(templateFilePath), null);

            pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(outputFilePath, 
                                       FileMode.Create));

            foreach (var kvp in fieldsValuesCollection)
            {
                acroFields.SetField(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            }


            pdfStamper.FormFlattening = false;

            pdfStamper.Close();
```

Comment: Would you also share the PDF in question?

Comment: I pasted a part of that pdf in my post. You mean screen shot of the whole pdf?

Comment: No, I meant the whole PDF. @safetyOtter seems to have posted an appropriate answer meanwhile, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the "Show text field overflow indicator" setting being triggered.  You can turn it off in your client here in Acrobat Reader's Preferences:
[image]

Sorry, I don't think you can actually disable it at the field level. Maybe enabling multi-line for the filed will keep it from showing.

Comment: Thanks. How would I enable multi-line field using the code I posted?

Comment: `text.Options = TextField.MULTILINE` where text is a reference to the textbox in question

Comment: In my code I am using AcroField. Can textbox be obtained from AcroField? I do not have textbox being used directly in my code.

Comment: although, unless your completely building the pdf in code,  it might be easier to just edit the pdf in acrobat and set the field there

Comment: maybe `acroForm.setFieldProperty("field.name", "fflags", PdfFormField.FF_MULTILINE, null);` i stole that, no idea if it works.

Comment: How about using setFieldProperty method? I haven't tried it because I do not know what will be the property name for this case.

Comment: @safetyOther, I was able to set the multiline using your suggested code, but multi-lines does not auto increase the field height. This means the overflow symbol still shows up. So now I want to able to auto-adjust the acrofield height for multi-line cases.

Comment: I looked for a while, couldn't find anything.  But found a snarky message board post that says that this is impossible: [Link](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Changing-the-size-height-width-of-an-acrofield-dynamically-tp2148831p2148835.html)  So I'd reccomend that if at all possible, pre-change the actual PDF to the required height.

Comment: Ok. I think with pdf there are some limitations unlike html which I and a lot of web developers out there am used to. This auto-size with multi-line feature is impossible to achieve in pdf using code, is my conclusion.